# Passing values using a href

Tags: php, google-maps, xampp

I have created a database on phpadmin and I have extracted  info from an xml file to the database, my database field consist of time, latitude,longitude ,depth and magnitude.i have a table displaying all the information on a webpage and i have a field containing a link,while clicking on the link,it supposed to direct me to a google map api and it must extract the latitude and longitude info from the database in which i'm having the issue to pass the value of latitude and longitude automatically,any help.here's my code

```
<?php
    require('dbconnect.php');
    $query="SELECT * from earthquake_xml";
    $result= mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    echo "Query Executed Successfully ";
    $numRow =mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "<br> Number Of Rows:".$numRow;
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align:center;

}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Latitude</td>
        <td>Longitude</td>
        <td>Depth</td>
        <td>Magnitude</td>
        <td>Google Map </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if($numRow>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Time'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Latitude']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Longitude']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Depth']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Magnitude']. "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='googleMap.php?longitude= '' '>Click here</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }




    }

    ?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my googleMap.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#map{
    height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
function initMap(){
    var myLatLng={lat:-36.5806,lng:-73.6355};
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    center:myLatLng,
    zoom:8
    });

    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var pos={
                lat:-36.5806,
                lng:-73.6355
            };

            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:pos,
                map:map,
            });

            map.setCenter(pos,marker)
        },function(){
            handleLocationError(true,map.getCenter());
        });
    }else{
        handleLocationError(false,map.getCenter)
    }
}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You better remove your api key from the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML page you can easily pass latitude and longitude as a query string.

```
echo "<td><a href='googleMap.php?longitude=".$row['longitude']."&latitude=".$row['latitude']."'>Click here</a></td>";
```

To get the same latitude and longitude just update your script with the `GET` request.

```
function initMap(){
    var myLatLng={lat:'<?php echo $latitude ?>',lng:'<?php echo $longitude?>'};
    ....// so on
}
```

Comment: i have used the get request but it isn't working.
function initmap(){
var myLatLnh={ lat:"<?php echo $_GET['Latitude'];?>",
lng:"<?php echo  $_GET['Longitude'];?>"
};
etc.....  
@HappyCoding

Comment: @fairytale what issue you're facing

Answer (score 0):

You can use geolocation api directly from php.

You can call an url like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

And receive a structured json response like this one:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Stati Uniti",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, Stati Uniti",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4223664,
               "lng" : -122.084406
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4237153802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0830570197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.42101741970851,
                  "lng" : -122.0857549802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

You can do this call using curl.

Ref. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start